# How to fix : you must call initialize() before you can use the dao

Tags: android

I am using Ormlite, and on one list I ask like this :

```
For the first Method:

 With Method inside as name is : getEmailUserListSearchByLastNameForOrmLite :

databaseOrmLiteManager.insertMeeting(new MeetingUser("Salle Ricocarpe", "point sur avance batiment", Collections.singletonList(Control.getEmailUserListSearchByLastNameForOrmLite("cocoRicocarpe")), "10"
                , "30", "25", "12", "2020"));

For the second method :

And An another one with method as name is : getEmailUserListSearchByDesignationOfMeetingForOrmLite

        databaseOrmLiteManager.insertMeeting(new MeetingUser("Salle André", "On s'y remet", (Control.getEmailUserListSearchByDesignationOfMeetingForOrmLite()), "10"
                , "30", "25", "12", "2020"));


For The First method call I receive exception :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in interface java.util.List


For the second method call, I receive exception :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must call initialize() before you can use the dao

public static List<User> getEmailUserListSearchByDesignationOfMeetingForOrmLite() {

ListUseForProjet.setListDataExampleUser();//TODO A SUPPRIMER après avoir mis BDD

List<User> listParticpant = new ArrayList<>();

listParticpant.addAll(ListUseForProjet.userList);


Log.i("TEST", "************CLASS CONTROL, Method getEmailUserListSearchByDesignationOfMeeting --> index liste USER LIST NAME MEETING : " + listParticpant);
        return listParticpant;
    }



public static User getEmailUserListSearchByLastNameForOrmLite(String name) {

ListUseForProjet.setListDataExampleUser();//TODO A MODIFIER POUR ADAPTER A BDD
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        User userSearch = new User();


        for (int i = 0; i < ListUseForProjet.userList.size(); i++) {

            if (ListUseForProjet.userList.get(i).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {//name

                users.add(userSearch);
                userSearch = ListUseForProjet.userList.get(i);
            }
        }

        Log.i("TEST", "************CLASS CONTROL, Method getEmailUserListSearchByLastName : index liste USER LIST NAME : " + userSearch.getEmailAddress());

        users.clear();//TODO Verifie si on le conserve pour l'aspect mémoire

        return userSearch;
    }

For the DatabasOrmLiteManager :

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils;
import com.ricocarpe.project4mareu.models.MeetingUser;
import com.ricocarpe.project4mareu.models.User;

import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseOrmLiteManager  extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {




    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "basededonnee.sqlite";//Pour ensuite aller sur le téléphone
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



    public DatabaseOrmLiteManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);//la doc m'apprend que l'on peut mettre la base dans un package raw
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {//il sera invoqué une fois lors de la création de la base de donnée

        try {


            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, User.class);

            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, MeetingUser.class);


            Log.i("DATABASE","***********Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method onCreate --> onCreate invoked");

        }catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","******************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method onCreate --> can't create Database",exception);
        }

        // here we try inserting data in the on-create as a test//TODO partie à effacer juste pour test
        RuntimeExceptionDao<User, String> dao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(User.class);
        // create some entries in the onCreate
        User user = new User("coco","nuts","coconuts@yahoo.fr");
        dao.create(user);
        user = new User("toto","toto","toto@toto.com");
        dao.create(user);
        Log.i(DatabaseOrmLiteManager.class.getName(), "***Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager********** TEST A EFFACER dans DatabaseOrmLiteManager, created new entries in onCreate: " + user);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {//dès lors que je mets à jour la structure de ma base de donnée

        try {

            //TODO ATTENTION ICI ON SUPPRIME LA TABLE BDD
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource,MeetingUser.class,true);//cette fonction droptable pour exemple, cette fonction supprime la table
            //si un upgrade, on commence par détruire la table

            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource,User.class,true);

            onCreate(database,connectionSource);

            Log.i("DATABASE","****************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method onUpgrade --> onUpgrade invoked");

        }catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","****************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method onUpgrade --> can't upgrade Database",exception);
        }
    }

    public void insertMeeting(MeetingUser meetingUser){


        try {
            Dao<MeetingUser,String> dao = getDao(MeetingUser.class);

            dao.create(meetingUser);
            Log.i("DATABASE","***************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method insertMeeting --> onUpgrade meeting invoked");

        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","**************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method insertMeeting --> can't insert meeting Database",exception);
        }

    }

    public Dao<User,String> getDao(User user) throws Exception{

        Dao dao = getDao(User.class);

        if (dao == null){

            try {

                dao = getDao(User.class);

                dao.queryForAll();
                //dao.createIfNotExists(user);
                Log.i("*****NOUVEAU DAO","****class DatabaseOrmLiteManager*************DAO new NOT get");
            }catch (java.sql.SQLException e){
                Log.e("*****NOUVEAU DAO","****class DatabaseOrmLiteManager*************DAO new NOT get "+e );
            }

        }
        return dao;
    }


    public void insertUser(User user){


        try {
            Dao<User,String> dao = getDao(User.class);

            dao.create(user);//TODO A voir quelle méthode on utilise, test complet à faire ta modif

            Log.i("DATABASE","*************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method insertUser --> onUpgrade User invoked");

        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","*************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method insertUser --> can't insert User Database",exception);
        }

    }



    public List<MeetingUser> readMeetingList(){

        try {
            Dao<MeetingUser,String> dao = getDao(MeetingUser.class);
            List<MeetingUser> readMeetingListShow = dao.queryForAll();

            Log.i("DATABASE","****************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method readMeetingList --> readMeeting list is invoked");
            return readMeetingListShow;

        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","***************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method readMeetingList --> can't readMeeting list Database",exception);
            return null;
        }


    }


    public List<User> readUserList(){

        try {
            Dao<User,String> dao = getDao(User.class);
            List<User> readUserListShow = dao.queryForAll();

            Log.i("DATABASE","*************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method readUserList -->  readMeeting list is invoked");
            return readUserListShow;

        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e("DATABASE","*************Class DatabaseOrmLiteManager, Method readUserList --> can't readMeeting list Database",exception);
            return null;
        }

    }

}

For the Class USer :

import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

import java.io.Serializable;

@DatabaseTable (tableName = "T_Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "idUser",generatedId = true)
    private int idUser;//TODO pour essai sur table et vision bon enregistrement

    @DatabaseField
    private String firstName;

    @DatabaseField
    private String lastName;

    @DatabaseField
    private String emailAddress;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;

    }

    public User() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email Address : "+emailAddress;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}

For the class MeetingUser:
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "T_Meeting")
public class MeetingUser implements Serializable{


    @DatabaseField
    private String placeOfMeeting;

    @DatabaseField
    private String objectOfMeeting;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "T_Email",canBeNull = false,foreign = true,foreignColumnName = "idUser",foreignAutoCreate = true)
    private List<User> usersList;

    @DatabaseField
    private String hourMeeting;

    @DatabaseField
    private String minuteMeeting;

    @DatabaseField
    private String dateMeeting;

    @DatabaseField
    private String monthMeeting;

    @DatabaseField
    private String yearMeeting;



            public MeetingUser(String placeOfMeeting, String objectOfMeeting, List<User> usersList, String hourMeeting, String minuteMeeting, String dateMeeting, String monthMeeting, String yearMeeting) {
        this.placeOfMeeting = placeOfMeeting;
        this.objectOfMeeting = objectOfMeeting;
        this.usersList = usersList;
        this.hourMeeting = hourMeeting;
        this.minuteMeeting = minuteMeeting;
        this.dateMeeting = dateMeeting;
        this.monthMeeting = monthMeeting;
        this.yearMeeting = yearMeeting;

    }


All I read on the forum don't work for my example.
Thanks a lot for your help.
```

All things I find on the forum with OrmLite

public MeetingUser() {
        }

```
    public MeetingUser(List<User> usersList){
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "MeetingUser{" +
                "placeOfMeeting='" + placeOfMeeting + '\'' +
                ", objectOfMeeting='" + objectOfMeeting + '\'' +
                ", usersList=" + usersList +
                ", hourMeeting='" + hourMeeting + '\'' +
                ", minuteMeeting='" + minuteMeeting + '\'' +
                ", dateMeeting='" + dateMeeting + '\'' +
                ", monthMeeting='" + monthMeeting + '\'' +
                ", yearMeeting='" + yearMeeting + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getPlaceOfMeeting() {
        return placeOfMeeting;
    }

    public void setPlaceOfMeeting(String placeOfMeeting) {
        this.placeOfMeeting = placeOfMeeting;
    }

    public String getObjectOfMeeting() {
        return objectOfMeeting;
    }

    public void setObjectOfMeeting(String objectOfMeeting) {
        this.objectOfMeeting = objectOfMeeting;
    }


public List<User> getUsersList(){
        return usersList;
    }

    public void setUsersList(List<User> usersList) {
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    public String getHourMeeting() {
        return hourMeeting;
    }

    public void setHourMeeting(String hourMeeting) {
        this.hourMeeting = hourMeeting;
    }

    public String getMinuteMeeting() {
        return minuteMeeting;
    }

    public void setMinuteMeeting(String minuteMeeting) {
        this.minuteMeeting = minuteMeeting;
    }

    public String getDateMeeting() {
        return dateMeeting;
    }

    public void setDateMeeting(String dateMeeting) {
        this.dateMeeting = dateMeeting;
    }

    public String getMonthMeeting() {
        return monthMeeting;
    }

    public void setMonthMeeting(String monthMeeting) {
        this.monthMeeting = monthMeeting;
    }

    public String getYearMeeting() {
        return yearMeeting;
    }

    public void setYearMeeting(String yearMeeting) {
        this.yearMeeting = yearMeeting;
    }
}
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in interface java.util.List

java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must call initialize() before you can use the dao